# CryptoJSAES inserts a space during the encryption. Can't decrypt afterward

Tags: php, aes, cryptojs

I am using the CryptoJS v3.1.2 from code.google.com/p/crypto-js to encrypt a string and store it i a cookie to be decrypted afterward using the corresponding PHP helper https://github.com/brainfoolong/cryptojs-aes-php.

For some reason I don't know, time to time, the result of the encryption cause the CT to have spaces in the string. When there's space, the PHP helper cannot decrypt it. If I removed the spaces it doesn't decrypt either.

Here the JS snippet:

```
var my_encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(phrase), 'MYSALT', {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString();
return my_encrypted;
```

Here the PHP snippet:

```
$decrypted              = cryptoJsAesDecrypt('MYSALT', $password);
```

The $password is taken from the cookie without any other modifications

Comment: Debugging is more difficult by including function in the encryption call. Use intermediate variables and you will be able to see the exact input and output of the encryption. My guess is that `.toString()` is failing because the encrypted output is incorrect for `toString`, instead encode with Base64.

Comment: @zaph where should I encode with Base64 ?